# Can't load keras after packing with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, cx-freeze

I have packed an application with cx_Freeze but when I start the application I get the following error:

```
ERROR:root:UNEXPECTED ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ai_hound.py", line 78, in run
  File "ai_hound.py", line 51, in load_models
  File "D:\PyPrj\FP2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 58, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "D:\PyPrj\PF2\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\lazy_loader.py", line 41, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\PGD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

That sounds wrong to me - cx_Freeze should pack a standalone version of the programm. So why it try to run files from the venv I have created for the project (**D:\PyPrj\FP2\venv**) and from my local Python installation (**C:\Users\PGD\AppData\Local...**)?!

This is my **setup.py**:

```
import sys, os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARA'] =     os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "tcl", "tcl8.6")
os.environ['TK_LIBRARA'] =     os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "tcl", "tk8.6")

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["time", "sys", "os", "base64", "cv2", "logging", "codecs", "shutil", "zipfile", "fitz", "pandas", "numpy", "tensorflow", "PIL", "io", "tkinter"],
                     "includes": ["tkinter", "tensorflow"],
                     "include_files": [ os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "tk86t.dll"), os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, "DLLs", "tcl86t.dll") ],
                     "excludes": []}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "AI Hound",
    version = "1.0.1",
    description = "AI Hound",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("ai_hound.py", icon="icon.ico", base = base)]
)
```

In the build-folder I do have 2GB of files and there is a tensorflow-folder with the subfolders python/keras! So I guess the EXE-file do not run the packed Python but my local installation...

Any suggestions what I have overlooked?

Comment: If I use import keras instead of from tensorflow import keras then I get another error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.engine.base_layer_v1'... Seems like the sub-modules are not copied over or somehow not accessable.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution...

1st I edited the script and used:

```
import keras
```

instead of `from tensorflow import keras`.

2nd I added keras to the package-list:

```
"packages": ["time", "sys", "os", "base64", "cv2", "logging", "codecs", "shutil", "zipfile", "fitz", "pandas", "numpy", "tensorflow", "PIL", "io", "tkinter", "keras"],
```

3rd I installed `lazy_loader` in the version **0.2** with pip:

```
py.exe -m pip install lazy_loader
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `"keras"` to the `"packages"` list of the `build_exe_options` and to use the latest cx_Freeze version (which one are you using?), it should support `tensorflow`.

Regarding your comment:

> That sounds wrong to me - cx_Freeze should pack a standalone version of the programm. So why it try to run files from the venv I have created for the project (D:\PyPrj\FP2\venv) and from my local Python installation (C:\Users\PGD\AppData\Local...)?!

I believe that cx_Freeze is running the standalone version of the program. The paths shown are filenames attached to code objects which presumably do not get actualized when the frozen application is moved. You can let cx_Freeze replace these absolute paths through relative ones by adding an entry

```
'replace_paths': [("*", "")]
```

to the `build_exe_options`. See [issue #247](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/247) on the cx_Freeze repository and the links therein.

Comment: Thanks - I tryed to add keras but it did not help till I installed lazy_loader 0.2. That and manual settings the modules List did the trick!

Comment: Sounds great. Please post an own answer with your solution and mark it as accepted.

Comment: OK - I have done that. Thanks again for you help.